# Errors when trying to run protractor tests with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver, protractor

I am trying to run protractor test on IE browser and I get an errors:

the conf.js capabilities

```
capabilities:
{
  'browserName': 'Internet Explorer'
},
```

the console errors:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found the problem.

1) First I downloaded the IE
[IEDriverServer](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

2) Run IEDriverServer.exe.

3) In protractor conf.js: change the seleniumAddress to the port shown in the popup window

> seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:5555',